# How to DataFrame.groupby a field containing list variables

Tags: python, list, pandas, grouping

I have a dataframe of this kind

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1':pd.Series(data = ['a','b','c','d'], index = [0,1,2,3]), 'key2':pd.Series(data = [3,4,2,3],index = [0,1,2,3]), 'key3':pd.Series(data = [0.3,0.5,0.3,0.3],index = [0,1,2,3]), 'key4':pd.Series(data = [[1,2,3],[4,3,6],[1,2,3],[1,2]], index = [0,1,2,3])})
```

I want to do:

```
df.groupby('key4').describe()
```

But it's giving an error.

My purpose is to create groups with similar values in key4

Comment: Please describe *giving an error*

Comment: You're grouping by 'key4' which  contains lists as elements, firstly this is a bit odd for pandas, secondly what are you expecting as the output. When I run your code it produces an empty df, presumably because it cannot groupby that column

Comment: Also it's a bit pointless to groupby by a column that contains values that cannot be hashed which is mandatory for operations on the groupby object

Comment: This would work if instead of lists you had tuples as the values

Comment: Yes it works with tuples. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't groupby by any column that contains an unhashable type, a list is one of those, for instance if you did `df.groupby('key4').head()` produces the error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

If instead you had tuples as the data then you can groupby that column, you can convert by doing the following:

In [454]:

```
df['key4'] = df['key4'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
df
Out[454]:
  key1  key2  key3       key4
0    a     3   0.3  (1, 2, 3)
1    b     4   0.5  (4, 3, 6)
2    c     2   0.3  (1, 2, 3)
3    d     3   0.3     (1, 2)
```

You can then groupby that column call `describe` on it:

```
In [455]:

df.groupby('key4').describe()
Out[455]:
                     key2  key3
key4                           
(1, 2)    count  1.000000   1.0
          mean   3.000000   0.3
          std         NaN   NaN
          min    3.000000   0.3
          25%    3.000000   0.3
          50%    3.000000   0.3
          75%    3.000000   0.3
          max    3.000000   0.3
(1, 2, 3) count  2.000000   2.0
          mean   2.500000   0.3
          std    0.707107   0.0
          min    2.000000   0.3
          25%    2.250000   0.3
          50%    2.500000   0.3
          75%    2.750000   0.3
          max    3.000000   0.3
(4, 3, 6) count  1.000000   1.0
          mean   4.000000   0.5
          std         NaN   NaN
          min    4.000000   0.5
          25%    4.000000   0.5
          50%    4.000000   0.5
          75%    4.000000   0.5
          max    4.000000   0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

you could first convert that column to strings and then do describe on that:

```
df.groupby(df.key4.astype(str)).describe()
```